# <> operator in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table like this

```
ID   Name    IsDeleted
1    Yogesh  Null
2    Goldy   1
```

Now when I run this query

```
select  * 
from tableName 
where IsDeleted <> 1
```

I should get `ID 1` record, But I am not getting it,

But when I run this

```
select  * 
from tableName 
where IsDeleted is null
```

I get `ID 1` record,

Why am I facing this behavior ??
Isn't `NULL <> 1` is a true statement in SQL ??

`IsDeleted` is a `bit` type field with `Allow Null true`

Comment: `NULL` means _"no value"_ and always requires special treatment when used with boolean comparisons.  It won't be included in your `<>` not-equal unless you also check `IS NULL`.

Comment: Just to emphasize: This is true not only for <>, but for every other operator as well - <>, =, in, between, >, < etc. will NEVER return rows with NULL values - nor will they if you negate the logic using NOT.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt, every operator but `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` of course... ;)

Comment: @Lucero Argl, forgot about those. You are right, of course :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select * from table 
where COALESCE(IsDeleted, 0) <> 1 
-- or ISNULL instead of COALESCE. 
--ISNULL seems to be better in subqueries, but it's not ANSI SQL.
```

or

```
select * from table 
where IsDeleted <> 1 or IsDeleted IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Comparing something with `null` will always result in `unknown`. That is why you need to use the `is` operator to compare `null` or use functions like `COALESCE` or `isnull` to replace `null`

Answer (score 1):

```
select  * 
from tableName 
where isnull(IsDeleted,0) <> 1
```

Answer (score 1):

you compare different types. in this case its an other type (unknown) and not comparable

use the or statement to compare each type seperate

```
WHERE IsDeleted <> 1 OR IsDeleted is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Learn about NULL - a comparison with NULL (in standard SQL) yields UNKNOWN, which is not true nor false (and the reason why your expectation is not met).

Try this:

```
PRINT CASE
    WHEN 1 = NULL THEN '1 = NULL'
    WHEN 1 <> NULL THEN '1 <> NULL'
    ELSE '1 is neither = NULL nor <> NULL'
END
```

You can either first make sure that you don't have a NULL value (for instance by using the `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` functions), or use a condition with the operator `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Normal practice would dictate that if you had a column that essentially was a true false, yes no type of field then you should use a bit field with the default value set to 0.

So in your case above you could just run this:

```
select  * 
from tableName 
where IsDeleted = 0
```

But in answer to your above question, if the Null is a true NULL value in the table then this will work for you:

```
select  * 
from tableName 
where IsDeleted is null
```

or

```
select  * 
from tableName 
where isnull(IsDeleted,0) = 0
```

to get record 1 and

```
select  * 
from tableName 
where IsDeleted is not null
```

to get record 2

Good luck

Paul.